# Lua - Downloaded Image files not working, and the remote and local file sizes are different

Tags: lua

Please could someone help me with the following as I can’t seem to download any gif files successfully. When I try to open them, they all return an error/claim to be ‘broken" image files.

In trying to understand why the downloaded files didn’t work, I discovered that the size of the remote file was different to what I believe I’d downloaded? (And all the downloaded files appear to be the same size).

It’s clear something’s not right, i just can’t work out what it is..??

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local https = require( "ssl.https" )
local lfs = require "lfs"

local rFiles = {
{"/images/backButton.gif"},
{"/buttons/off.gif"},
{"/buttons/off_h.gif"},
{"/buttons/25.gif"}
}

for k,v in pairs(rFiles) do
    for _,v1 in pairs(v) do
        local file = assert(io.popen('curl -s https://download1.mios.com/L_sPhoneUI_layout'..v1..' | wc -c', 'r'))
        local output = file:read('*all')
        file:close()
        local curloutput = v1.." : Remote file size via curl request = "..output
        local body, code = https.request("https://download1.mios.com/L_sPhoneUI_layout"..v1)
        if not body then error(code) end
            local file_to_check = "/mnt/nas"..v1 -- file to save locally as
            local f = assert(io.open(file_to_check, "wb")) -- open in "binary" mode
            f:write(body) -- save the content to a file 
            f:close()   
            local size = lfs.attributes (file_to_check, "size")
            local lfsoutput = v1.." : Downloaded file size via Lfs request = "..size
            print(curloutput.." -> "..lfsoutput)
            print("---------")
    end
end
```

The print output is as follows..(all downloaded files are 3132 in size?)

```
/images/backButton.gif : Remote file size via curl request = 672
-> /images/backButton.gif : Downloaded file size via Lfs request = 3132     
---------     
/buttons/off.gif : Remote file size via curl request = 1608
-> /buttons/off.gif : Downloaded file size via Lfs request = 3132     
---------     
/buttons/off_h.gif : Remote file size via curl request = 1598
-> /buttons/off_h.gif : Downloaded file size via Lfs request = 3132     
---------     
/buttons/25.gif : Remote file size via curl request = 1651
-> /buttons/25.gif : Downloaded file size via Lfs request = 3132     
---------
```

Comment: Use `w+b` if the file already exists.

Comment: Hi @shingo - still same result - did the above script work when you tried it ?